# How to handle a new window and switch to it in Vba

Tags: excel, vba, selenium

I am trying to handle a new widow and then switch to it. In VBA using selenium and excel

I have tried various means such as

`driver.getWindowHandle` 
-however, I can't get it to work, maybe a syntax thing or not viable with vba

```
Dim currentWindow As Selenium.Window
```

and then `Debug.Print currentWindow`  this will error out

and many more to no avail

```
Option Explicit

Private driver As Selenium.ChromeDriver

Sub test()

    Dim FindBy As New Selenium.By
    
   
    Set driver = New Selenium.ChromeDriver
    
    driver.Start baseUrl:=""
    driver.Get "/"
   
     
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution is `driver.SwitchToNextWindow.Activate`

This will go to the next window